# Compactness of a linear function

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, compact-operators

Consider $T:L^2(0,1)\rightarrow L^2(0,1)$ such that
$$ (Tu)(x)=\int_0^x u(t) dt \quad \forall x \in (0,1).$$
How could one prove that $T$ is compact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integral operators are where the original notion of compact came up through Arzela-Ascoli. Your integral operator maps bounded subsets of $L^2$ into equicontinuous sets of functions. This because, for $0 \le x \le x' \le 1$,
$$
        |(Lf)(x)-(Lf)(x')| \le \int_{x}^{x'}|f(t)|dt \\
                 \le \left(\int_{x}^{x'}|f(t)|^2dt\right)^{1/2}\sqrt{x'-x}.
$$